# Android: send result to an Activity cleaning the top of BackStack

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have 3 Activities: A, B, C.

I want that Activities work as follows:

A startActivityForResult B;
B can start C or send result to A;
C can go back to B or send result to A.

When B send result to A, B  must be removed from backstack.
When C send result to A, B and C  must be removed from backstack.

I'm not able to send result to A from C. This means that A must be reusmed (NOT RECREATED) and onActivityResult() must be callled to process result:

I have tryed with this code but A is recreated and onActivityResult() is not called!!

```
public class C extends Activity{
    sendResultToA(){
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), A.class);
        i.putExtra("dataBean", dataBean);
        i.putExtra("args", "save");
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Any ideas to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: post the original code. the above snippet does not compile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can solve this problem,

`From Activity A -> startActivityForResult(ActivityB)`

`From Activity B -> startActivityForResult(ActivityC)`

If all success set the result by following way.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("dataBean", dataBean);
i.putExtra("args", "save");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i); //pass your intent
finish(); // Call finish to remove ActivityC from the stack
```

If you receive success in ActivityB then do the same. 
In `onActivityResult` check whether result successful or cancelled using  `Activity.RESULT_OK` and `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

Comment: Ok i had already thought at this solution, but i thought that it was not so smooth due to the call of 'onActivityResult()' in B (useless). I wanted to jump directly to A. But i have tryed just now and it works very good (B does not appear even for a moment). Thank you!